# could not able to fetch the list of data from firebase. facing Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
2020-12-13 21:46:56.838 4030-4030/com.troll.trollmemes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.troll.trollmemes, PID: 4030
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.troll.trollmemes.Fragment.HomeFragment$2.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:96)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

facing this issue - getting the null object error

my code in the line get publisher i am getting null excemption. what will remove the error and display the data from database.

```
public class Post {
    private String postid;
    private String postimage;
    private String description;
    private String Publisher;

    public Post(String postid, String postimage, String description, String publisher) {
        this.postid = postid;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.description = description;
        Publisher = publisher;
    }

    public Post() {

    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postid;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postid) {
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    public String getPostimage() { return postimage; }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return Publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        Publisher = publisher;
    }
}
```

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost)
    {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item,viewGroup, false);

        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Post post = mPost.get(i);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage()).into(viewHolder.post_image);

        if (post.getDescription().equals("")){
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
        }

        publisherInfo(viewHolder.image_profile, viewHolder.username, viewHolder.publisher, post.getPublisher());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPost.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView image_profile, post_image, like, comment, save;
        public TextView username, likes, publisher, description, comments;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            publisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
        }
    }
    private void publisherInfo (final ImageView image_profile, final TextView username, final TextView publisher, String userid){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                publisher.setText(user.getUsername());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private List<Post> postList;

    private List<String> followingList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

        checkFollowing();

        return view;
    }
    private void checkFollowing(){
        followingList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Follow")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("following");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                followingList.clear();
                for (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                readPosts();
                //new
                //postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readPosts(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for (String id : followingList){
                        assert post != null;
                        if (post.getPublisher().equals(id))
                        {
                            postList.add(post);
                        }
                        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: in last part of the code readpost part I am getting this error. what will remove this error

Comment: Please add your database structure to the question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of more of the posts in your database doesn't have a `publisher` property. That causes `post.getPublisher().equals(id)` to fail, as `post.getPublisher()` is null.

If the absence of a `publisher` property is expected, you can simple skip posts without a publisher:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        postList.clear();
        for (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            for (String id : followingList){
                assert post != null;
                if (post.getPublisher() != null &&post.getPublisher().equals(id)) {
                    postList.add(post);
                }
                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

If a post is always supposed to have a publisher, you'll want to check which node in your database is not following that rule. I'd also recommend in that case to write security rules to ensure the `publisher` is always present, based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation

Comment: Ss now its not showing error but the data is not showing. What could be the code to add

Comment: I don't know why that would be. Did you step through the `onDataChange` in a debugger yet? Does it contain the data you expect now?

Comment: Yes Frank I have checked that. Data is getting populate inside.But its not displaying

Comment: E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Comment: E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
Getting these error now

Comment: /? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 457, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
2020-12-16 16:06:03.016 2128-6873/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
2020-12-16 16:06:03.016 2128-6873/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

Comment: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

Comment: At first glance none of those seem related to the non-rendering of this data. Are your `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` being called?

Comment: yes Frank its not getting called. Kindly help me to figure this out. I have put the breakpoit and ran the app and the debugget is not stoping at oncreateviewholder and binder

Comment: Post Adapter itself not getting triggered

Comment: If your `onCreateViewHolder` is not getting called, that means that no data is coming from the database. We have no way of knowing why that is. A first step would be to stop ignoring errors, and implemening `isCanceled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Hi Frank,

thanks a lot for the replies.

somehow I managed to sort out the issue